# Compare uploaded photo with existing photos like matching photo using C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to Compare Uploaded photo with Existing Photos ???
I want to make Web application in which I have number of photos at particular location. When user upload its photo, It scan with all existing photos and gives result whether anyone match or not.
**Note :** Matching does not mean exact photo, It may vary in goggles on eyes etc etc. So, It must match appropriately. It is like Crime Branch people use their system to check whether photo match with their Criminal Records.
Please help me to get this.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far. Interesting question though

Comment: This is a super interesting question, and it's also one worthy of devoting your life to research at a university for. It's certainly possible that there are some good tutorials, books, and maybe even open source libraries out there to get started, but don't expect this to be just a "oh, I should jot down a quick class to check my database for images" kind of deal.

Comment: I'm not familiar with C#, but will something in C++ be of any help?

Comment: Interesting or not, this is not a suitable question for StackOverflow. If you want a library recommendation - it's off topic. If you want the code - it's way too broad (and you need to show your own attempts anyway). This is not an easy task, you will need to do a lot of research on your own if you plan on coding this yourself. Feel free to ask specific questions if you hit any problems with implementing specific parts of your code though

Comment: @MatthewHaugen Check out OpenBR. Makes something like that surprisingly simple. And I totally agree that it is a very hard problem! But do check that project out!

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV will do what you need to do very easily.

You will have to read through the code but it can match images for you..

Doing this yourself will be a lot more difficult and a math intensive.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

http://opencv.org/about.html

(Make sure you marked answered if this helps)